# How to split a text that contains String and Int and store into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, store

So basically I have a java program that reads a txt file using `BufferedReader`.

The text file contains all the information about the movies. The first column is the code, the second is the title and the third is the rating.
e.g

```
1 Titanic 44  
34 Avengers 60  
2 The Lord of the Rings 100
```

So 1 is the code, Titanic is the title and 44 is the rating etc.

My problem is that I have made a class Movie(int code, String title, int rating)
and I want to store all the informations in there but I can't figure out how to split the text. `split(" ")` doesn't seem like it would handle the case where a title has embedded spaces (e.g The Lord of the Rings).

What I really need is the ability to strip off the first and last fields based on space as a separator, and treat all other interior spaces as part of the title, not as separators.

Comment: Show us what you tried ...

Comment: Just because you don't know the size of the array you'll get from `split(" ")` doesn't mean you can't use it.  It just means you have to check the length of the array instead of assuming a constant length.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @nicomp no it isn't, this stinks of homework. I have no problem helping students that have shown some effort, but im not going to solve the only gotcha which is probably the whole point of the assignment

Comment: @nicomp are you honestly trying to tell me he arbitrarily decided to come up with the exercise on his own?! OK sport.

Comment: OP mentions an attempt to solve the problem with `split(" ")` and the encountered problem. That appears to be within the requirements for asking a question.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct, `split` that you already tried is inappropriate. Based on the pattern you are showing, the delimiters seem to be the first and the last space in each line and everything between them is the title. I recommend to find the index of these spaces and use [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

Eg:

```
String text = "2 The Lord of the Rings 100";
int firstSpace = text.indexOf(' ');
int lastSpace = text.lastIndexOf(' ');

String codeText = text.substring(0, firstSpace);
String title = text.substring(firstSpace, lastSpace);
String ratingText = text.substring(lastSpace);
```

Comment: My problem is that I have to put the informations in an ArrayList of type "Movie(int code, String title, int rating)" (It is something like this: "ArrayList <Movie> movies = new ArrayList <Movie>();"). The way you showed me makes everything (code, title, rating) into a string so I can't do "movie.add(code,title,rating)". (sorry for not making it clear...first time using this site. Also it is not necessary to use .split)

Comment: @Pauline You can use `Integer.parseInt(codeText);` to get `code` for example. Then call the `Movie` constructor to make a `Movie` object

Comment: You're a patient person, @ManosNikolaidis. Bless you.

Comment: @ErickG.Hangstrom How am I supposed to learn when I don't ask these kind of silly questions? :)

Comment: Better trim that string first. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use split(" ")
Use

```
String[] foo = split(" ")
```

The first element in foo will be the first integer. Convert that to an integer type. Then step through the remaining elements and append them into one string, except for the last element in foo, which will be your last integer and you can convert that to an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as you mentioned *I can't use split(" ") because some titles (e.g The Lord of the Rings) has spaces between the title.*

```
String str = "2 The Lord of the Rings 100";
String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Get the data for `arr`

```
String code  = arr[0];
String rate = arr[arr.length-1];
String title = "";
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    title += arr[i]+" ";
}
```

Run the code

```
System.out.println("code = " + code);
System.out.println("rate = " + rate);
System.out.println("title = " + title);
```

And it is the result:

```
code = 2
rate = 100
title = The Lord of the Rings
```

May this help you...

Answer (score 1):

See Regexp and Matcher classes with pattern : `(\d*)\s(.*)\s(\d*)`

EDIT : Example

```
@Test
public void testRegExp(){
    String text = "2 The Lord of the Rings 100";
    String patternString = "(\\d*)\\s(.*)\\s(\\d*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("CODE : " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("TITLE : " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("RATE : " + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String line = "1 Titanic 44";
int code = Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[0]);
String title = line.split(" ")[1];
int rank = Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
```

Comment: Doesn't handle titles with embedded spaces.